# django rest api application not starting

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a restful API created on django RESTful Framework, all of the sudden API application is not starting up when I am running command

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

Here is the complete exception log:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f778bc98f28>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/developer/note_api/main/models.py", line 21, in <module>
    Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 486, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 390, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1164, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1028, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1365, in names_to_path
    if field.is_relation and not field.related_model:
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 94, in related_model
    apps.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/developer/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
```

I have tried rebooting server multiple times, and secondly change the manage.py script but its not helping.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you run migrations?

Comment: @AkhilBatra same if I run python manage.py migrate

Comment: More like `File "/home/developer/note_api/main/models.py", line 21, in <module> Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)` is trying to create `Token` too early.

Comment: did you run `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: @AkhilBatra same error on python manage.py makemigrations as well

Comment: @PlumbInFront Where are you calling this `Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)`?

Comment: @Praveenkumar in models.py for user in User.objects.all():
    Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

Comment: Have you edited `manage.py`?

Comment: You cannot use the models until all of them are created, i.e. don't try to create a Token when you're importing the app.

Comment: @akhilsp no change in manage.py

Answer (score 0):

delete your virtual env and make a new one, install your packages and then remove all your migrations except **init**, remove your database tables(if you have no imprtant datam if not create a new database and use it) and run:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake <app name> zero
```

then try to makemigrations again and then migrate and runserver, please let me know if problem solved

Comment: How do I delete the migration?

Comment: like you delete other files from your pc:) just go to the folder and right click on and delete it, but dont delete __init__

Comment: I am trying to find the location where django keep migrations

Comment: migrations file are inside migrations folder of your app